# In Google sheets is it possible to have a combined chart with stacked columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I currently have a simple combined chart with a revenue line and columns.  For what I am trying to communicate with this graph, I would really like to have stacked columns in addition to my revenue line.

Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931681/google-combo-charts-with-stacked-bar-and-lines

Comment: "_...you can copy paste a graph from sheets to slides_". I know. The same way they can be used in docs or downloaded etc. But it is neither an issue you have with slides per se nor the solution will affect them. Your addition of the "google-sheets-charts" is correct. Please also check the suggested link by @Nick

Comment: We don't really do cross-site duplicates.  It's unfortunate, but that's the way the system is laid out.  It's okay to answer it here and reference that SO question in your answer.

Comment: You can do this using a Google script/code, see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931681/google-combo-charts-with-stacked-bar-and-lines) for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but for anyone reading it, this is indeed possible. Once you've created a Combo Chart, the chart editor has a "Stacking" option under "Setup" just below the "Chart Type" Dropdown.

The options are "None", "Standard", and "100%".

Answer (score 1):

You can have stacked column chart combined with line.

1. First choose chart Combined
2. Add all data and Series
3. And then customize every Series in details, here:

[image]

At the end you have

[image]